# Set a border around coin-slider 

Tags: css, slider

I want to place a white border around the slider like this >> [image] .

I tried using `.coin-slider img { border: 2px solid white;}` , but it didn't work.

Coin-slider link >> [Coin-slider official site](http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/)

HTML:

```
<div id='coin-slider'>

                     <img src='images/slideshow1x.png' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow2x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow3x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow4x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
.coin-slider img { border: 2px solid white;}
/*.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; } */

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
/*.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }*/
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF;}

.cs-title { width: 545px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev, 
.cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 10px; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, `coin-slider` is the `id` of the `div`, and not `class`, whereas in your CSS you are referring to `.coin-slider` everywhere.

Change `<div id='coin-slider'>` to `<div class='coin-slider'>` in your HTML and everything should work fine.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4kqjD/) is a demo.

Comment: Thanks alot. I didn't realise this small oversight. The class is actually for the .js file haha.

Answer (score 0):

***White Border for the Coin-Slider*** can be set by adding the style

```
border: 2px solid white;
```

to the Cascading Stylesheet 'coin-slider-style.css' as

```
.coin-slider {overflow:hidden; zoom:1; position:relative; border:2px solid white;}
```